# Particular example of a non-vanishing analytic function f in unit disc |z|<1.

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

This question is from Ponnusamy and Silvermann complex analysis section : Cauchy inequality.

Also please note that they are not homework problems. I am trying myself.

Question: Give an example of a non -vanishing analytic function f in unit disc |z| <1 with infinitely many zeroes.

Keeping uniqueness theorem in mind I need to find a sequence in |z|<1 with no limit point.

Now I choose $ a_1 =0.1 , a_2=0.11, a_3 =0.111, a_4 =0.1111$ and so on.

I think this will not have any limit point but that's due to the reason that I am unable to find limit point of this sequence (I think it doesn't exists).

> But can you please prove rigorously why limit point doesn't exists?

If I am wrong kindly tell an example that will work.

Many thanks!!

Comment: There exists such a function. The uniqueness theorem tell you the zeroes of your function cannot have a limit point in the open disk but they can have such point on the boundary.

Comment: your sequence converges to $\frac{1}{9}$, so it has a limit point

Comment: It is easier to construct a non-constant holomorphic function on the half-plane $\mathbb{H} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \mathfrak{I}(z) > 0\}$ having infinitely many zeroes. Then compose this function with a conformal map between the unique disk and $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: Perhaps the Wikipedia article [q-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol) may be helpful.

Comment: $\sin(1/(z-1))$

Comment: Your sequence converges to $0.11111\dots=0.\overline{1}=\frac19$, so 
the limit here exists and it is contained in the unit disc. To find such a function,it is easier to consider $\sin(iz)$ on the upper plane (infinite zeros), and then pre-compose with the inverse of the [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform). In this way you obtain an analytic function on the unit disc with infinite zeroes

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{10^{-n}}{1-z})$$
Does it converge, is it analytic, where are its zeros